# pandas.read_csv : OperationalError: table has no column named 1

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, pandas

[image]

I'm trying to upload a csv to a sqllite table on windows using :

The sqllite table and csv have the same field names and start with:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
"case" TEXT, 
 ......
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
UNIQUE ("case")
)
```

I have the following class:

```
class Sqllite_utilities(object):

    def __init__(self, db_path, table_name):
        self.db_path = db_path
        self.table_name = table_name

    def upload_csv_to_table(self, path_to_csvfile):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)
        df = pandas.read_csv(path_to_csvfile)
        df.to_sql(self.table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index_label='id')
```

at the command line:

```
s = Sqllite_utilities(settings.SETTINGS_PATH+"\\data.db",'test2')

In[3]: s.upload_csv_to_table('C:\Users\ne\Desktop\jtest.csv')
C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:1201: UserWarning: The spaces in these column names will not be changed. In pandas versions < 0.14, spaces were converted to underscores.
  chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-b530f5199977>", line 1, in <module>
    s.upload_csv_to_table('C:\Users\dnir\Desktop\jtest.csv')
  File "F:\ENVS\r2\j1\utilities.py", line 41, in upload_csv_to_table
    df.to_sql(self.table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index_label='id')
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1201, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 470, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1503, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 664, in insert
    self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1291, in _execute_insert
    conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(), data_list)
OperationalError: table test2 has no column named 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I think you got it, I'm getting a new error, and I'll look into that seperately:

```
  df.to_sql(self.table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index_label='id')
File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1201, in to_sql
  chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 470, in to_sql
  chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1503, in to_sql
  table.insert(chunksize)
File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 642, in insert
  keys, data_list = self.insert_data()
File "C:\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 609, in insert_data
  "duplicate name in index/columns: {0}".format(err))
 ValueError: duplicate name in index/columns: cannot insert id, already exists
```

Comment: does the table exist already, without that column name?

Comment: Yes the table exists and has no column called '1'

Comment: so then your pandas dataframe columns need to match the db column names

Comment: you got me thinking , I opened the csv and added a screenshot. what may be happening is that pandas is taking the first row as column headers, rather than data

Comment: yeah you have no headers, so try something like `df = pandas.read_csv(path_to_csvfile, names =['col1name', 'col2name'])` which match the database columns

Comment: I redownloaded the csv this time with headers. Please see edit

Comment: *I redownloaded the csv this time with headers*...what does this mean? Did you follow @jeremycg's suggestion in your `.read_csv()` call? By default `read_csv` assumes first row is header.

Comment: Thanks , I just got it working. I created a copy of the csv with the column headers present this time. I then got the error in the edit above. I was able to get it working just now by changing the last line in  def upload_csv_to_table to 'df.to_sql(self.table_name, conn, if_exists='append', id=False)'

Answer (score 6):

The problem lies in the index column, Pandas has an index of the dataframe as a column 'index'. If you don't want insert records without it, try this;

df.to_sql(..., index=False)